# tableview filtered rows get reloaded after selecting row

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a search bar for my tableview by:
`let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`
and in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblSearchTable.delegate = self
        tblSearchTable.dataSource = self
        loadListOfCountries()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tblSearchTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
           }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

    }
```

My problem is that, when I search for items, the table shows the filtered rows but when I tap/click a row, the tableview rows get reloaded (all items). This is my didselectrow function:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected row")

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
           }
```

The text `selected row` gets printed but the the viewcontroller isnt getting dismissed but instead, just like I said, reloads all the original items in tableview.

Here are the extensions, might need them when helping me:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension Search: UISearchBarDelegate {
    // MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension Search: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

And here's the search function:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredArray.removeAll()

        var x = 0
        for a in dataArray{

            if(  a.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())){

                filteredArray.append(a)


            }
            x = x + 1
        }


        self.tblSearchTable.reloadData()
    }
```

Here's the complete code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class Search : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{




    var dataArray = [String]()
    var dataLine = [String]()
    var dataColor = [String]()

    var filteredArray = [String]()
    var filteredLine = [String]()
    var filteredColor = [String]()


let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    @IBOutlet var tblSearchTable: UITableView!


       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblSearchTable.delegate = self
        tblSearchTable.dataSource = self
        loadListOfCountries()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tblSearchTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
           }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
           }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: UITableView Delegate and Datasource functions
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected row")

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)


        //var ClassViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        //ClassViewController.funcforsearch()
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return filteredArray.count
        }
        return dataArray.count

    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        //cell.textLabel?.text = candy.name
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = candy.category
        return cell

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }


    // MARK: Custom functions

    func loadListOfCountries() {
        //get some array here
        self.tblSearchTable.reloadData()

    }
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredArray.removeAll()

        var x = 0
        for a in dataArray{

            if(  a.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())){

                filteredArray.append(a)


            }
            x = x + 1
        }


        self.tblSearchTable.reloadData()
    }

}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension Search: UISearchBarDelegate {
    // MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension Search: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: please see the updated code

Comment: Just this:`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
           }`

Comment: remove `self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)` code and see. And what is the purpose of this line of code?

Comment: to remove it from the screen. I showed it as popup. So after the user selects a row, that popup should be dismissed.

Comment: what is `popup` here? The search table?

Comment: yes. the viewcontroller with the search table.

Comment: But why do you want to hide the search controller when you click on the cell? By doing this the actual table with all the data is showing up.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo Can you pleas show the code how you are showing popup of SearchTableController?

Comment: @Mr.UB the concept of that is to go to the next viewcontroller after selecting a row.

Comment: See my complete code

Comment: But you should not dismiss the search controller. BTW, how are you moving to next view controller. where are you calling the segue?

Comment: i did not see the segue you are using to goto next view controller here.